# Plotting open balls for the given metric spaces

Tags: plotting, topology

We're given a metric space (R,d) defined as follows: $$d(x,y) = |x-y|$$

We need to draw a open ball for this metric space with centre and radius of our choice.

Open ball definition: For a fixed $x$ and $r$ we just need to plot $d(x,y) < r$. (that's what I think)

```
d[x_, y_] := Abs[x - y]

RegionPlot[d[x, y] < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

Which gave:

[image]

Is this OK?

Comment: There's gotta be a question in here somewhere  :-D.  Seriously though, you have definitely plotted a portion of the region where `Abs[x - y] < 2`, so I'm not sure what you are asking

Comment: No. It's not OK. in your definition of metrics $x$ and $y$ are two points of your metric space. In your `RegionPlot` they are two coordinates of one point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$d(x,y)$ is the distance between ***two*** points.
$d(x,y)=|x-y|$ means the length of vector $x-y$. This vector can be in $n$-dimensional space. Your metrics in Mathematica would be `d[x_List, y_List] := Norm[x - y]`.

Suppose you have $x_0$ and you want find all points $y$ in 2D such that $d(x_0,y)<r$. Now $y=(y_1,y_2)$ is a point in 2D, it's not the second coordinate!

The following code will do that:

```
d[x_List, y_List] := Norm[x - y];
x0 = {1, 1};
r = 1;
RegionPlot[d[x0, {y1, y2}] < r, {y1, 0, 3}, {y2, 0, 3}]
```

Surprisingly that's a disk!

Although I think that $|x-y|$ is normally interpreted as Euclidean distance, we can easily define our `d` differently, as @bill commented. We can define

```
dAbs[x_List, y_List] := Norm[x - y, 1];
```

as another norm and plot the result:

```
RegionPlot[{d[x0, {y1, y2}] < r, dAbs[x0, {y1, y2}] < r}, {y1, 0, 
  3}, {y2, 0, 3},PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

You can easily "upgrade" it to 3D without changing **anything** in your norm definitions

```
x03d = {1, 1, 1};
Show[RegionPlot3D[#1[x03d, {y1, y2, y3}] < r, {y1, 0, 3}, {y2, 0, 
     3}, {y3, 0, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> None, 
    PlotStyle -> {#2}] & @@@ {{d, {Blue, Opacity[0.4]}}, {dAbs, 
    Orange}}]
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `d[x_List, y_List] := Norm[x - y, 1];` to get the Abs( ) norm.

Comment: FWIW, we do have `EuclideanDistance[]` and `ManhattanDistance[]` built-in.

Comment: @J.M. Indeed  `EuclideanDistance[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}] == Norm[{a, b, c} - {x, y, z}]` yields `True`