# Guide to plotting Metric Spaces

Tags: plotting

**Pre-amble**
OK, I'm fairly new to Mathematica. I've covered things like integration, partial differentiation, and plotting basic graphs. I'm now moving into Metric Spaces. I've had a search around for a guide/handout/book for plotting open/closed balls and spheres without any success. I have managed very basic plots with the help or one or two posts here - thanks for that - but here are some examples of what I'm hoping to be able to do.

**Question**
Using Mathematica Desktop, how can I plot open *Bd((0,0),1)*, closed *Bd[(0,0),1]* balls and spheres *Sd((0,0),1)* for metrics such as:

d((x1,x2),(y1,y2)) = |y1 - x1| + 3|y2 - x2|

d((x1,x2),(y1,y2)) = 4|y1 - x1| + d0(x2,y2)

If you've covered metric spaces, you'll know that an open ball doesn't include the points at the outermost edges (hence it should have a dotted line); a closed ball includes the points at the outermost edges (hence a solid line); and a sphere is just the points at the outermost edges. These are not just drawing a Ball or Sphere using {x,y,z}.

This post has some good information on plotting open balls but I'd appreciate some help with how to define the metrics shown above then plotting the associated balls.
[Plotting open balls for the given metric spaces](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112518/plotting-open-balls-for-the-given-metric-spaces)

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: Try `RegionPlot` or `ContourPlot`. For open balls, just set the style of the boundary lines to `None`.

Comment: Henrik, thanks. Yes, RegionPlot is the way to go with producing the plot. Any help with defining the metric, the d[] command?

Comment: The second metric would be `f = Function[{x, y}, 
  4 Abs[Indexed[x, 1] - Indexed[y, 1]] + 
   Unitize[Indexed[x, 2] - Indexed[y, 2]]]`, wouldn't it? The balls are indeed not easy to plot. For radius $<1$, the closed balls are horizontal line segments; you could draw the with the `Line` primitive. For radius $\geq 1$ the closed ball would be the region between two vertical lines, the lines included. You could use the primitive `Rectangle` to visualize thoses.

Comment: That second metric could well work, Henrik. I just need to find out how to plot it, whether using Line, Rectangle or otherwise. Thank you for the help you've provided.

Answer (score 2):

```
f = Function[{x, y}, Abs[Indexed[x, 1] - Indexed[y, 1]] + 3 Abs[Indexed[x, 2] - Indexed[y, 2]]];
```

Closed ball:

```
RegionPlot[f[{x, y}, {0, 0}] <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100
 ]
```

Open ball:

```
RegionPlot[f[{x, y}, {0, 0}] <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 BoundaryStyle -> None
 ]
```

Spehere:

```
ContourPlot[f[{x, y}, {0, 0}] == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100
 ]
```

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks for this. This works perfectly for the first metric. Do you have any thoughts on the second metric involving the discrete metric d0?

Comment: Syntax::sntxf: "{x,y}|" cannot be followed by "->Abs[Indexed[x,1]-Indexed[y,1]]+3Abs[Indexed[x,2]-Indexed[y,2]]".  this make me confusing but at least in version 11 gives error

Comment: @AnxonPués Ah yes, the `|->` syntax was only added recently.