# Plotting an open ball with a discrete metric

Tags: plotting

A simple question but the answer is elusive... well, for me anyway!

Given a metric space defined as d((x1,x2),(y1,y2)) = 4|y1 - x1| + d0(x2,y2), how can I plot open Bd((0,0),1) with Mathematica?

Henrik Schumacher has been a great help [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264917/guide-to-plotting-metric-spaces) suggesting the metric would be f = Function[{x, y}, 4 Abs[Indexed[x, 1] - Indexed[y, 1]] + Unitize[Indexed[x, 2] - Indexed[y, 2]]] however I've had no luck with any attempt at producing a plot. I just get an empty grid.

Can anyone help with the relevant code needed to produce a plot?

Many thanks

Comment: Wolfram has an explanation here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteMetric.html. Briefly, if the two points are the same point, d0 is zero otherwise d0 is 1.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you define a distance function of:

```
dist[p1_, p2_] := 
  4 Abs[p1[[1]] - p2[[1]]] + If[p1[[2]] == p2[[2]], 0, 1];
```

A ball with this metric are all points that fulfill the equation:

```
dist[{x, y}, {0, 0}] == 1
```

We may solve this by:

```
Reduce[dist[{x, y}, {0, 0}] == 1, {x, y}, Reals]
```

[image]

This means: if y!=0 then x==0, that is the y axis without the origin. And if y==0 then x==+/- 1/4. A plot of these points looks like:

```
Graphics[{Red, Thickness[0.005], InfiniteLine[{{0, -1/4}, {0, 1/4}}], 
  Point[{{-1/4, 0}, {1/4, 0}}], Black, Point[{0, 0}]}, Axes -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {0.5 {-1, 1}, 0.5 {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Daniel, many thanks for this. Two questions, if I may. 1) How did you get the {{x -> 0 if y > 0 || y < 0 }, etc} to print? 2) I note that you have InfiniteLine with 0 to -1/4 and 0 to 1/4 however it seems InfiniteLine has possibly 'overruled' the 0 to -1/4 and 0 to 1/4. Should InfiniteLine be just Line?

Comment: 1) if a statement has no ";" at the end, it will print its output. ";" will prevent this. 2) `InfiniteLine[{{0, -1/4}, {0, 1/4}}]` means an infinite line passing though points: {0, -1/4}, and {0, 1/4}  For the graphics, you may as well use an ordinary line : `Line[..]`

Comment: Got it! Many thanks, Daniel. Greatly appreciated.